# Does corona enable social games? Can I integrate google analytics?

Tags: game-engine, coronasdk

I'm considering starting learning corona development, What I'm building need to have a server side (heroku/parse or something else), Can I do it with corona? can I integrate any other SDK? Does it supports google analytics?

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a bunch of server side stuff with Corona - autoLAN and GameMinion are both great examples of third party addons to make social games easier in Corona, although they aren't necessarily what you will use looking at them will give you a good idea of what is possible.

For Google Analytics, depending on what you were hoping to track, you'd likely be better off considering something like Flurry.

Comment: autoLAN is for LAN games as I understand and GameMinion is on beta.
Is there something more solid for server side?

Comment: PubNub could be another option; I haven't done a lot with it but they have a bunch of great docs/samples online already, I'd suggest checking that out if you need something more established.